# Mysql query running for indefinite time in version 5.5 and gives output in version 5.1

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am using a simple MySQL query with a `CONCAT` `function` in `mysql`.

MySQL Query:

```
SELECT 
(
    SELECT 
        CONCAT
        (
            '/', 
            LOWER
            (
                REPLACE
                (
                    loc_name,
                    ' ',
                    '-'
                )
            )
        ) AS l1_url 
    FROM 
        lmap 
    WHERE 
        lvl = 1
) l1_url
```

The above query runs in MySQL version 5.1 and give the output, But when i try to run the same query in MySQL version 5.5 it is running out for indefinite time and does not gives any output. Are there any significant changes in MySQL version 5.5.

**UPDATE: Table Structure**

```
CREATE TABLE lmap 
(
    id int(10), 
    loc_name varchar(32), 
    parent int(10), 
    lvl int(10) 
); 

INSERT INTO lmap VALUES(1, 'abc', 0, 1); 
INSERT INTO lmap VALUES(2, 'av', 0, 2);
```

Comment: what is the datatype for > ""1) l1_url"" it its a varchar text use --> lvl = "1) l1_url" in WHERE clause

Comment: @zerkms I am using nested query to concat all the values returned like this /aa-bb-cc

Comment: @swapnesh the datatype for lvl is int

Comment: @Prateek then why  ")" in you Where matching clause as 4 opening braces are already matched with closing braces ? make it little readable plz :)

Comment: @swapnesh The last three opening braces are for the second select statement which is getting all the values and concatenating it and the first brace is again for a select statement which gives me the output in a single column. There are 4 opening and 4 closing braces are there.

Comment: Can you please provide us with the example data and the expected result? Btw, it was working in 5.5: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29538/1

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius the table structure for lmap               CREATE TABLE lmap
(
  id int(10),
  loc_name varchar(32),
  parent int(10),
  lvl int(10)
);

INSERT INTO lmap VALUES(1,abc,0,1);
INSERT INTO lmap VALUES(2,av,0,2);

Comment: I added it to the question update. Still, you have not yet provided the most important part - expected result. And again, it was working in 5.5 in my given example. P.S. you missed `'` on `abc` and `av`

Comment: Same here, checked on Fiddle, and working for both, 5.1 and 5.5.

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius the expected result is like this "/aa-bb"

Comment: @Prateek, so you have `abc` and expect `/aa-bb`? If yes, I don't follow... :/ (Because the query you wrote gives `/abc` as an aswer)